# What does this law of applicative mean?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Applicative is declared as

```
class   Functor f   =>  Applicative f   where
pure    ::  a   ->  f   a
(<*>)   ::  f   (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
```

One of applicative's laws is:

```
x <*> y <*> z = ( pure (.) <*> x <*> y) <*> z
```

where  `(.)` is composition between functions:

```
(.) ::  (b  ->  c)  ->  (a  ->  b)  ->  (a  ->  c)
f   .   g   =   \x  ->  f   (g  x)
```

On the right hand side of the law,

- does `pure (.)` have type `f((b   ->  c)  ->  (a  ->  b)  ->  (a  ->  c))`?
- does `x` have type `f(b->c)`?
- does `y` have type `f(a->b)`?
- does `z` have type `f(a)`?

On the left hand side of the law,

- does `x` have type `f(a->b->c)`?
- does `y` have type `f(a)`?
- does `z` have type `f(b)`?

Thanks.

Comment: For equality to hold, the types have to be the same (up to alpha renaming) on both sides.

Comment: which is why I have my question.

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797365/1126841) for some intuition.

Comment: The LHS of that law should be `x <*> (y <*> z)`, else it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

The applicative laws are easier understood in the equivalent [monoidal functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) representation:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  pureUnit :: f ()
  fzip :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
--pure x = fmap (const x) pureUnit
--fs<*>xs = fmap (\(f,x)->f x) $ fzip fs xs
--pureUnit = pure ()
--fzip l r = (,) <$> l <*> r
```

Then, the law you're asking about is this:

```
fzip x (fzip y z) ≅ fzip (fzip x y) z
```

where by `p ≅ q` I mean, equivalent up to re-association of the tuple type, i.e. explicitly

```
fzip x (fzip y z) ≡ fmap (\((a,b),c)->(a,(b,c))) $ fzip (fzip x y) z
```

So this is really just an associative law. Even better visible when written with an infix `(⋎) = fzip`:

```
x ⋎ (y ⋎ z) ≅ (x ⋎ y) ⋎ z
```

Answer (score 2):

Stating the law again for ease of reference (which I have corrected by putting the parenthese in, `(<*>) is left associative so the ones on the LHS of the equality are necessary):

```
x <*> (y <*> z) = ( pure (.) <*> x <*> y) <*> z
```

let's start with your first question:

```
On the right hand side of the law,

does pure (.) have type f((b   ->  c)  ->  (a  ->  b)  ->  (a  ->  c))?
```

Yes it does. `(.)` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`, so `pure (.)` must have type "`f` of that".

We can use this to determine the types of the other identifiers here. In the expression `m <*> n`, `m` and `n` have the general types `f (a -> b)` and `f a`. So if we take `m` as `(.)`, which has the type shown above, we see that `n` - which corresponds to `x` on the RHS of the equality - must have type `f (b -> c)`. And then `pure (.) <*> x` will have type `f ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))`, which by the same reasoning means `y` will have type `f (a -> b)`. This produces a type of `f (a -> c)` for `( pure (.) <*> x <*> y)` and of `f a` for `z` - and thus an overall result type, for the whole RHS (and therefore also the whole LHS) of `f c`.

So to summarise, just from analysing the RHS, we see that:

- `x :: f (b -> c)`
- `y :: f (a -> b)`
- `z :: f a`

It's now easy to check that these work out on the LHS too - `y <*> z` will have type `f b`, so `x <*> (y <*> z)` will have type `f c`.

I note that there's nothing clever involved in the above, it's just simple type algebra, which can be carried out without any advanced understanding.